# Elasticsearch 1.6 reboot on ubuntu pid-file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch, pid

Has anyone here installed the latest version of Elasticsearch on a Ubuntu? If so you might have encountered the elasticsearch PID_DIR issue when rebooting the Ubuntu server.

The file PID file is written to this directory:  /var/run/elasticsearch but it's not actually there on Linux reboot because it gets deleted by ubuntu.This was not an issue in earlier versions (or at least not in 1.3.9). Is it possible to make elasticsearch write the pid-file to another location that doesn't get cleaned up by elasticsearch?

Thanks in advance,

Arno

Comment: you are right there is an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11594)  the work arounds are mentioned in the link

Comment: Thanks, I'll post the workaround as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until elasticsearch fixes it , one possible workaround is to adapt the 
file /etc/init.d/elasticsearch

change 
PID_DIR="/var/run/elasticsearch"
to
PID_DIR="/var/run"

the PID file will now be created directly in the run folder.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11594

Comment: makes sense probably u can also put the  link to the open-issue in the answer